# Exclude the files to deploy by Capistrano

Tags: ruby, capistrano

I deployed the project by capistrano from git.

There are some files which are stored in git but not want to be copied to deploy server.

in git, file structure.

```
myapp     - mainapp
          - somesetting.txt
          - _NoWanttoDeploy.txt // I don't want to deploy this file
```

These are deploy.rb

```
# config valid for current version and patch releases of Capistrano
lock "~> 3.11.2"

set :application, "myapp"
set :repo_url, "ssh://app@git.example.com/~/myGit/myapp.git"

set :branch, 'master'
set :deploy_to, "/var/www/html/myapp"

set :linked_dirs, fetch(:linked_dirs, []).push('static')

set :keep_releases, 3
```

How can I set???

Comment: Anything related to PHP?

Comment: I deploy php and python project, but it might not be related php itself, I will delete the tag.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

how about [copy_exclude](https://www.rubydoc.info/gems/capistrano/2.5.2/Capistrano/Deploy/Strategy/Copy)?

```
set :copy_exclude, "_NoWanttoDeploy.txt"
```

Comment: Somehow `copy_exclude` doesn't work.I googled around and found the same case, so I gave up to use `copy_exclude`. use `namespace :deploy do
    desc 'mytest'
    task :mydelete do
        on roles(:app) do
            execute "rm -rf /var/www/html/myapp/current/_NoDeploy"
        end
    end
    after :publishing, :mydelete
end` instead , but thank you very much for your comment.